# tri-boot window, ubuntu 20.04 and 22.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi

I already have windows 11 and ubuntu 20.04 installed on my laptop, but now i need ubuntu 22.04 as well for ROS2 humble alongside my ubuntu 20.04 with ROS1 noetic.
Currently I'm trying to install Ubuntu 22.04 like i did  the dual boot for ubuntu 20.04, but when i try to boot through the usb it shows the grub menu with 5 options (1. try and install ubuntu, 2. ubuntu safe graphics, 3. oem installation, 4. boot from next drive, 5. uefi firmware) and when i select any of the first two its showing SQUASHFS error, and iso file is not the issue i think because i re downloaded and burned several times the iso file on the usb using rufus, so how should i do this?

Comment: Please verify whether the ISO is corrupt or not https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu#1-overview

Comment: yea I've verified several times the files are fine